# how to set relative path in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, path

sounds like silly question but I cannot make it work.
I have Script folder to include for Telerik RadScriptManager
and with absolute patch it works but don't know how to
set relative path. Scrupts aret at this location C:\WORK\SRC\BMM\ASSETS\SCRIPTS
and the solution is in here C:\WORK\SRC\BMM so this would be root.
thanks

Comment: If the solution will be always be there you can do: System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartUpPath, "ASSETS\\SCRIPTS")

Comment: a bit more on what you have done might help me understand. what language are you using?

Comment: this is script patch input in telerik property so cannot use any language statement. <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" Runat="server" ScriptPath="C:\WORK\SRC\BMM\ASSETS\SCRIPTS"  />